# Ошибка Package Manager при запуске проекта Unity 2018

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Помогите пожалуйста, справисьса с ошибкой. Пробовал отключать windows defender потом перезакружать пк, но нечего не сработало. Буду очень благодарен за помощь. (у меня windows 10 home).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: перевод ошибки: `Убедитесь, что процесс не заблокирован антивирусной конфигурацией`

Comment: Я могу проверить, но незнаю как(

Comment: Я все ещо не решил проблему. Поиогите кто-то пожалуйста.